# Laravel: Combining the results with UnionAll with count

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Lets just say I have 2 column in a table resume_profiles

```
   current_location      city
    | Chennai  |    | Kolkatta   |
    | Mumbai   |    | Ahmaedabad |
    | Pune     |    | Kolkatta   |
    | Kolkatta |    | Pune       |
```

I need to combine these result into a single SET, So I'd have something like this:

```
   City        Aggregate
| Chennai    |    | 1 |
| Mumbai     |    | 1 |
| Pune       |    | 2 |
| Kolkatta   |    | 3 |
| Ahmaedabad |    | 1 |
```

**Query:**

```
$current_locations = ResumeProfile::selectRaw('current_location as city');

ResumeProfile::selectRaw('city,count(*) as aggregate')
           ->unionAll($current_locations)
           ->groupBy('city')->get();
```

when i use the above query i'm getting the below query with the exception

**SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select city,count(*) as aggregate from `resume_profiles` group by `city`) union all (select current_location as city from `resume_profiles`))**

I don't no how to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try do this:

```
  $current_locations = ResumeProfile::selectRaw('current_location as city');

 $subquery=ResumeProfile::selectRaw('city')
       ->unionAll($current_locations);

   DB::table(DB::raw("({$subquery->toSql()}) AS s"))
         ->selectRaw('s.city,count(*) as aggregate')
          ->groupBy('s.city')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a query like this

```sql
SELECT city, COUNT(*) aggregate
  FROM (
    SELECT current_location AS city FROM resume_profiles
    UNION ALL
    SELECT city FROM resume_profiles
  ) q
 GROUP BY city
```

Here is [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0ef573d24d0e4baeaa076c9a4e4a75d9)

I don't see an elegant way to express this using Eloquent or QueryBuilder. Just use a raw query

```php
$sql = <<<'SQL'
SELECT city, COUNT(*) aggregate
  FROM (
    SELECT current_location AS city FROM resume_profiles
    UNION ALL
    SELECT city FROM resume_profiles
  )
 GROUP BY city
SQL;

$cities = DB::select($sql);
```

Tinker it:

```
>>> DB::select($sql);
=> [
     {#706
       +"city": "Ahmaedabad",
       +"aggregate": 1,
     },
     {#707
       +"city": "Chennai",
       +"aggregate": 1,
     },
     {#685
       +"city": "Kolkatta",
       +"aggregate": 3,
     },
     {#684
       +"city": "Mumbai",
       +"aggregate": 1,
     },
     {#687
       +"city": "Pune",
       +"aggregate": 2,
     },
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it works according to your needs.

```
$cityInfo = DB::table(DB::raw('(select current_location as city from resume_profiles union all select city from resume_profiles) as resume_profiles'))
    ->select(DB::raw('city, count(city) as total'))
    ->groupBy('city')
    ->get();
```